# Python: saving objects and using pickle. extension of filename

Tags: python, object, save, pickle, file-extension

Hello I´m trying using the next piece of code:

```
import pickle 
object = Object() 
filehandler = open(filename, 'w') 
pickle.dump(object, filehandler)
```

I would like to know what should be the extension of the file 'filename'.
Thank you!

Comment: filename represents any (string) value, you can choose the extension. E.g. "mypickle.pickle"

Comment: it does not matter. You are free to choose any filename or extension. But generally .pkl or .pickle is used for readability.

Comment: One more thing you should pay attention to: you should used binary mode with operation of pickling files. So 'w' should be 'wb'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with the file.

`filename` should be sufficient.

And don't use `object` as an identifier. It shadows the builtin `object`.

Comment: Yes, I know 'object' is the instantation.

Comment: @Peterstone: Python has a built-in *type* named `object`. You have a variable with the same name which hides this and any references to `object` will access something unexpected.

Comment: Missing the extension might look unprofessional to windows users

Answer (score 28):

You could use any `filename`, but as an FYI it's common to use ".p" (for obvious reasons).

```
pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

Read: [UsingPickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)

Comment: Seems like it would be very useful to save the object type in the filename too, eg. `MPLplots.Figure.p` or `Data.list.p` or `Data.nparray.p`

Comment: @john convention - other answers mention .pkl or .pickle so I guess it's not that strong of a convention though.